# Passing additional parameter to d3.svg.line()

Tags: d3.js, nested

I'm making a site that graphs datasets picked by the user from a large collection.  In order to normalize the plots (user option) I'm finding max(y) for each dataset and I'm trying to use that as a denominator in my `line().y()` but I can't figure out a good way to get it in.

The datasets are csvs that all look like this:

```
site0586,id,depth,age,sed,quant,conc,influx,level
1, 94297, 0.1400, 8.390, 0.097, 50.5100, 50.5100, 4.87496, "C0P0"
2, 94298, 0.1760, 45.690, 0.083, 52.5800, 52.5800, 4.35011, "C0P0"
3, 94299, 0.2030, 73.660, 0.135, 29.8500, 29.8500, 4.03080, "C0P0"
...
```

Default x and y are "age" and "conc" but are user-choosable.  User picks datasets and they get plotted on the same graph, one after another.  As plots are added the graph's scale adjusts to fit the overall max-x and max-y and earlier plots update to conform.  X's can vary between datasets by a good bit and y's can vary by five orders of magnitude so small-value lines can get considerably squashed.  Got this going with a little transitioning and it works great.

Sometimes User wants to see the y's with a [0,1] normalization so small-value trends will be visible on the same x-scale as large-value ones; that's an option.  Easy -- reset the y domain to [0,1] and divide each plot's y's by that dataset's max(y).  For the dots that works perfectly; for the lines I'm having a lot of trouble.

It's one graph so I build one data structure; as User picks each dataset I download it, `nest()` it and push it onto an array, and since I'm going to need the maxes later, while I'm there I find the domains of each variable, put them in an object called `heads` and append that to the nested data.  So my data structure looks like this:

```
datae:  [
{ "key": "300",
  "values": [
    {"site0300": 1, "id": 60383, "depth": 0,  ... }, ...
    {"site0300": 182, ... }
  ],
  "heads": { "depth": [0,5.9], "age": [107.4,16589.5], ...} 
},
{ "key": "586",
  "values": [
    {"site0586": 1, ...}, ...
  ],
  "heads": {...}
}
]
```

I've got my `line().y()` set up to (potentially) use a denominator that could be either 1 or thisData.max(y):

```
var lineFn = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[xVar]) })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[yVar]/normer) });
```

except I can't figure out how to get `datae[thisLineIdx].heads[yVar[1]]` into the call:

```
var lines = graf.selectAll('.line')
  .data(datae);

lines.enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr("d", function(d) { return lineFn(d.values) })
```

Each member of `lines` gets the right entry from `datae` but since svg.line() only wants to hear about arrays (and won't communicate anything from its insides) it only does anything if I call it with datae[thisLineIdx].values, and then datae[thisLineIdx].heads is inaccessible.

I could set up all the datae[idx].heads as a global but there must be a better way than that -- I just can't see any way to calculate that max(y) from within line(), nor any idiomatic way to include it in the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ach -- duh!  Been stuck on this (one day a week) for *ages*, and was halfway there all the time.  Now that last code block goes:

```
var lines = graf.selectAll('.line')
  .data(datae);

lines.enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr("d", function(d) { 
      normer = gOpts.normIt.state ? d.heads[yVar][1] : 1; 
      return lineFn(d.values) })
```

And now my lineFn() does what I want, when I want.

However, I dislike this solution because it does leave `normer` (declared at a higher level) floating around in a semi-global way, outside the relevant scope, ready to cause some other mischief.  So I consider this the dumb way and if anyone can suggest something more sophisticated I'd be very grateful.